# Function 'result arity'

Tags: terminology

Given a map from $m$-tuples to $n$-tuples, $m$ can be referred to as the 'arity' of the mapping. What's the terminology for $n$?

I feel like this *should* be brain-dead easy to find but my Google/StackExchange/WolframMathWorld-fu clearly isn't strong enough.

Comment: In my many years of mathematics I've never come across such a term.